# Creating a new layer in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, shortcuts

I'm new in Adobe Illustrator. Are there any other ways to create a new layer in Illustrator than pressing the button at the bottom of the Layers panel?  Is there a shortcut, like `Shift + Ctrl + N` in Photoshop? And for clarification - is there a way to create a new layer from the main menu? It seems layers are much more important in Photoshop, which has a separate `Layer` menu tab, missing in Illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is the default shortcut in Illustrator for a new layer.

`Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Menu Commands > Other Panel` And you can change it to match Photoshop's shortcut if you'd like (that's what I do).

[image]

The other way (besides the panel button) to create a new layer is via the **Layers Panel Menu**. There's no "new layer" item in the main app menu.

---

Illustrator layers are quite different than Photoshop layers.

Illustrator has an **Object Stack** which is contained in every Layer. Photoshop has no object stack. In Illustrator, it's often the *object stack* which is more imperative. Layers in Illustrator are typically more about *artwork organization* than actual construction and appearance.

In Photoshop, construction is often a mix of layer interactions, and indeed can *greatly* depend on layer interaction for some appearances. In Illustrator, layers are really more like "master **groups**" and don't *necessarily* interact with one another. It's the **object stack** in Illustrator which has interaction to a greater degree.